# iPhone SDK "clear" function not working-button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have a question relating to a button I made for my app. I am fairly new to iPhone development so please stay with me. When the "clear" button is clicked, it is programmed to  reset the text fields. The other "calculate" function works fine. The app runs perfectly until I press "clear". Then the app will completely freeze. The following is displayed in Xcode.The commented out is the error I get,  I think it is some sort of breaker:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
//Above error reads "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"
[pool release];
return retVal;
}
```

I feel like this is a simple mistake but I am unfamiliar with mobile development and just started it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: That's not where the actual error is occurring. That's just your program's entry point. Please paste the log and the real code.

Answer (score 0):

When this occurs, it usually means Xcode couldn't figure out where something went wrong. The best thing to do is to set a breakpoint in the first line of your `-clearButtonWasPushed:` method (or equivalent). Run it step by step, and then when it crashes to your main.m code, you'll know which line caused it. You might have overreleased something by mistake...

Alternatively, UITextField has a built in clear button, which you can activate programatically or in IB:

```
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```